# Django file validation error

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I've been struggling with file validation for a while now but I think I'm on the right track. I'm trying to validate an audio file 'sound' when I post a form. Whenever I try and submit the form I get  an `'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'content'`. The problem seems to happen at form.is_valid(). So far I have in forms:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_sound(self):
        file = self.cleaned_data.get('sound',False)
        if file:
            if not file.content-type in ["audio/mpeg","audio/mp3", "audio/wav"]:
                raise ValidationError("Content-Type is not mpeg")
            if not os.path.splitext(file.name)[1] in [".mp3",".wav"]:
                raise ValidationError("Doesn't have proper extension")
            return file
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Couldn't read uploaded file")




    class Meta:
        model = Places
        fields = [

            'usersave',
            'title',
            'longitude',
            'latitude',
            'sound',

        ]
```

in the view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def post_create(request):
    form= PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)


    if form.is_valid():

        # handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['sound'])
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Successfully Created')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


    context= {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'location/post_form.html',context,)
```

I'm not sure what the 'InMemoryUploadedFile' error is, and would much appreciate any advice that could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

wanted to comment but don't have enough reputation yet.

If you take a look at the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/#InMemoryUploadedFile) it seems you have to call `open()` first in order to access its content. The class instance itself `file = self.cleaned_data.get('sound', False)` doesn't have a `content` attribute as stated in the error. May you could try opening the file first?

Answer (score 1):

try this

file = self.cleaned_data.get('sound')

and

are you trying to upload the same audio file and getting the error? or you tried with other audio files also?